# Zend_Cache - "Datas must be string or set automatic_serialization = true"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to cache an array with Zend_Cache like this:

```
$cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
// $data is an array
$cache->save($data, 'externalData');
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Message: Datas must be string or set automatic_serialization = true
```

Even though the automatic_serialization is set tu true when initializing Zend_Cache in the bootstrap file:

```
protected function _initCache()
{
    $frontend= array('lifetime' => 7200,
                     'automatic_seralization' => true);
    $backend= array('cache_dir' => 'cache');
    $this->cache = Zend_Cache::factory('core',
                                       'File',
                                       $frontend,
                                       $backend);
}
```

What could cause this error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you just made a copy-paste error or a typo error, but, in the code you posted, you have :

```
$frontend= array('lifetime' => 7200,
                 'automatic_seralization' => true);
```

i.e. you are setting `automatic_seralization` to true, and not `automatic_serialization` : note the **i** in ser-**i**-alization.